# How can I get the response time of a HTTP request in elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am doing some monitoring for my api endpoints. I've already tried out with some http clients like httpoison, and hackney erlang library. But they don't give me http response time, do they? Did someone experience kind of this? It would be grateful if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your call in `timer:tc/1`. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1

In Erlang, that'd be something like:

```
{ElapsedUs, Result} = timer:tc(fun() -> hackey:get(Url) end).
```

Alternatively, Hackney supports reporting metrics (including timing) via folsom or exometer. See https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#metrics

Comment: Thz, but I've already tried with that one. It give me just function execution time. So, it's always greater than the  actual response time. When connection timed out, its return value is greater than the timeout value I set. That's why I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: How much greater? I find it hard to believe that function call overhead is even observable compared to an HTTP round-trip.

Comment: in milliseconds, I set timeout 10 ms in HTTPoison and made request. It's timeout and timer.tc give me like 12,13 ms

Comment: The 10ms timeout might only be accurate to a few milliseconds. That would explain why you're seeing 12ms elapsed. Erlang's only soft-realtime, after all.